# Dynamically Adding Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following html structure and am trying to add in option elements in the optgroups via javascript. I am using the jquery mobile framework as well.

Html as follows:

```
<form>
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="selectID">Look-up</label>
    <select name="select-native-4" id="selectID">
       <option>Choose...</option>

           <optgroup label="G1" id="group1">                              
           </optgroup>
           <optgroup label="G2" id="group2">
           </optgroup>
           <optgroup label="G3" id="group3">
           </optgroup>

           </select>
       </div>
  </form>
```

The javascript is as follows.

```
for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var item = array[i];
        var $option = $('<option> ' + item.name + ' </option>');
        $option.prop('value', item.memb);
        console.log(item.name);
        var tp = -1;
        switch(item.name){
            case 'group1' :
                tp = 1;   break;
            case 'group2' :
                tp = 2;   break;
            case 'group3' :
                tp = 3;   break;
        }
        console.log(tp);
        //$("#selectID :nth-child(tp)").append($option);

        $("#selectID").eq(tp).append($option);
    }
    $('#selectID').selectmenu('refresh');
}
```

I am confused as to why the .eq(n) does not append the $option object to the nth child of #selectID, which would be an optgroup. Thanks for any help!

Comment: post the whole script or a fiddle.

Comment: Why would you expect `.eq(n)` to add to a child? `.eq(n)` selects the `nth` element that matches the selector.

Comment: If you want the nth child, use `.children().eq(n)`.

Comment: that would hit the option, not the optgroup elements. see resolve below.

Comment: I'd help, but you ask questions and don't select answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 1 #selectID. You need:

```
$('#selectID optgroup').eq(tp).append($option);
```

This will hit the optgroups inside your select id.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is appending to the `Select` object not the `optgroup`.

`.eq(index)` gives you an object at that index that matches the selector. In this case there is only one select so you're away going to get it.

Here's how I would handle this example.

I would write the `$option` definition line like this.

```
var $option = '<option> ' + item.name + ' </option>';
```

In place of the `switch` statement I'd put this.

```
$("#"+item.name).append($option);
```

ID's should be unique for the entire HTML page so this should be the only group with that ID. That being the case you can add it directly to that `optgroup`

Comment: Why don't you think you can use `$` in a variable name? jQuery does, it uses the variable named `$` all the time.

Comment: Can't that cause conflicts with JQuerys `$` operator?

Comment: only with the dot notation: $.

Comment: What kind of conflict? A variable `Foo` doesn't cause a conflict with a variable `F`, so why would `$option` cause a conflict with `$`? Do you think there's something special about `$`? It's not an operator, it's just the name of a function.

Comment: @Barmar Updated to reflect this talk.